# How to automatically apply data validation and fill in the blanks

Tags: excel

It's quite a simple question but it's too specific that I don't really know how to solve.

we have a list of 1000+ leads with different types of status data that were input manually in the past. Now we are changing it to data validation with drop down list, but the list is too large to manually change the data validation for each cell, plus past data have spelling mistake and trailing space. How should I accomplish this?

Please see photo below for easier reference.

Thanks in advance,

[image: datavalidation]

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect Excel to correct all possible spelling mistakes?

I would suggest to mark those statuses that are already in validation list and manually correct the rest:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(CLEAN(TRIM(B2)),$G$2:$G$5,0)),CLEAN(TRIM(B2)),"Need to correct manually")
```

[image]

Correct `B` column cells manually:

[image]

Then *copy* and *paste values* of column `C`.